# The isExternalURL function from the IntuneMAMWebViewPolicyDelegate is not called

Tags: ios, swift, intune

I have implemented the iOS Intune SDK in my app. The app applies the MAM policies and is working properly. I am trying to implement the Webview content restrictions using the IntuneMAMWebViewPolicyDelegate and isExternalURL as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/developer/app-sdk-ios#displaying-web-content-within-an-application)

The isExternalURL function is never called.

This is the view containing my WKWebView

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import IntuneMAMSwift

class WebviewPage: UIViewController {

    let webViewPolicyDelegage = WebViewPolicyClass.init();
    
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        IntuneMAMPolicyManager.instance().setWebViewPolicyDelegate(webViewPolicyDelegage, forWebViewer: webView!)
        
        let webaddress = "https://www.google.com"
        
        if let url = URL(string: webaddress) {
            let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
            self.webView.load(urlRequest)
        }
    }
}
```

This is my delegate implementation

```
import IntuneMAMSwift

class WebViewPolicyClass: NSObject, IntuneMAMWebViewPolicyDelegate {
    
    func isExternalURL(_ url: URL) -> Bool {
        // TODO: Check if URL is external
        return true
    }
    
}
```

The app MAM policy is configured to require the managed Edge browser.

Any ideas why the delegate method is not called?

Comment: Maybe [add this code](https://github.com/msintuneappsdk/Chatr-Sample-Intune-iOS-App/blob/master/chatr/SettingsPage.swift) temporarily to your app to debug it.

Comment: Have you called `setCurrentThreadIdentity` with an empty string (or your current identity if your app is multi-identity) prior to displaying this view controller?

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 I tried calling setCurrentThreadIdentity but no success